# Shared Pointer on a thread counts 1 after join?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, boost-thread

Having a `boost::condition_variable` which waits for a thread to complete:

```
boost::condition_variable mContd;
boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> mThread;
```

Imagine, the Thread was started some time before, and now wait:

```
if(!mContd.timed_wait(tLock, boost::posix_time::seconds(1))) {
  // cancel thread if deadline is reached
  mThread.interrupt();
  mThread.join();

  std::cout 
    << "Thread count = " 
    << mThread.use_count() // still prints '1'
    << std::endl;

} else {
  // continue
}
```

So, when is this count set to a zero? I assumed, after a `join` a thread is finished. But when it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`use_count()` simply tells you how many `shared_ptr` object points to the same `boost::thread` object. It has nothing to do with whether the thread has terminated.

The counter will automatically get decremented when `mThread` goes out of scope.

If you no longer need the `thread` object, you could call `mThread.reset()`. That'll also cause `mThread.use_count()` to go down to zero.

Comment: This means, if mThread is global, only after program termination? At program start, the `use_count` is a zero, as intended.

Comment: @Benjamin: It's zero at startup because the shared pointer is empty. You can make it empty again by calling `mThread.reset()`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Objects can't properly delete themselves like that.

When the thread terminates, the `boost::thread` object representing it goes into a "finished" state, but it must still "exist" because `shared_ptr` is controlling it. You still have the one, now-"finished" `boost::thread` object that you have before, so the count is still 1.

In fact, in general, `boost::shared_ptr::use_count()` will *only* return `0` when it's representing a "null pointer" rather than an actual object that exists.

A direct analogy follows:

```
boost::thread mThread(&f); // Create thread object

mThread.interrupt();
mThread.join();            // Thread is now "finished"

cout << (mThread.get_id() == boost::thread::id());
// ^ Outputs `true`, because the object mThread is now in the
//   not-a-thread state, but of course it still must exist.
```